# How to change Button color in specific TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have an app like a quiz app. In tableViewCell there are 4 buttons for variants of the task. And I need to change color when the user is pressed the button, when I try to just change color in action of button the color of button changes in all table view Cells. But I need to change only in that, where I pressed. I already tried to write delegate, But it is giving the same result this is code how I wrote my delegate:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isHighlighted {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        } else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 34/255, green: 89/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

}

I already have added target actions to buttons.

```
var variant1 = UIButton()
var variant2 = UIButton()
var variant3 = UIButton()
var variant4 = UIButton()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "finalCell")!
    variant1 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
    variant2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
    variant3 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    variant4 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton


    if (numberOfVariants.count != 0) {
        let questionTextView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView
        questionTextView.text = "\(Questions[indexPath.row].content!)"
        variant1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant1ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        variant2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant2ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        variant3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant3ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        variant4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant4ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
          }
        return cell
    }
```

I already identified the indexPath of table view (if it is helpful), when the user clicked to button:

```
    func variant1ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    print("Variant1")
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
    globalIndexPath = intIndexpath
}
func variant2ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
    globalIndexPath = intIndexpath

}
func variant3ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
    globalIndexPath = intIndexpath


}
func variant4ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
    globalIndexPath = intIndexpath


}
```

This how its looks like in storyboard(If it is helpful)
[image]

Comment: You need change the color while the button is touched or change the color on selection?

Comment: @ReinierMelian when user selected one button change the color of this button.

Comment: You need to implement isSelected instead of isHighlighted property to display selected color.

Comment: @Surjeet I tried same problem. For example when I pressed first variant in the first cell it changes color of all first variants in all cells

Comment: You need to hold selectedIndexPath in a variable and within cellForRowAt func, you need to compare selectedIndexPath with indexPath. If both are same, then only you need to apply selected color otherwise apply normal color.

Comment: @Surjeet I know the logic that I have to do I don't know how to do this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using much more code than you really need to do this task, so this is another approach using `closures`, I have only one viewController in my storyboard and add a UITableView inside and a customCell called `ButtonTableViewCell` then I linked a normal UIButton to that cell as @IBOutlet and that is all, the full implementation is here

https://github.com/rmelian2014/SOButtonsTableViewCellQuestion

## EDITED

## ButtonTableViewCell

```
    import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBInspectable var selectedColor : UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var normalColor : UIColor = UIColor.blue

    static let cellHeigth : CGFloat = 360

    @IBOutlet var buttonsArray: [UIButton]!
    var selectedText : String?{
        willSet{
            guard newValue != nil else{
                return
            }

            var foundedIndex = -1
            for (index,text) in self.texts.enumerated() {
                if(text == newValue!){
                    foundedIndex = index
                    break
                }
            }

            guard foundedIndex != -1 else
            {
                return
            }

            self.buttonsArray[foundedIndex].backgroundColor = selectedColor
        }
    }
    var texts : [String] = []

    var buttonActionClosure : ((_ selectedText:String?)->Void)?

    func setupWithClosure(texts:[String],textSelected:String?,closure:((_ selectedText:String?)->Void)?)
    {
        self.texts = texts

        for (index,button) in self.buttonsArray.enumerated(){
            if(self.texts.count > index)
            {
                button.setTitle(self.texts[index], for: .normal)
            }
            button.tag = index
            button.backgroundColor = self.normalColor
        }


        self.selectedText = textSelected
        if(closure != nil)
        {
            self.buttonActionClosure = closure
        }


    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender:UIButton)
    {
        if(self.texts.count > sender.tag){
            let newSelectedText = self.texts[sender.tag]

            if(newSelectedText != self.selectedText){
                self.selectedText = newSelectedText
            }else
            {
                self.selectedText = nil
            }
        }
        if(self.buttonActionClosure != nil)
        {
            self.buttonActionClosure!(self.selectedText)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.buttonActionClosure = nil
    }

}
```

## ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dictOfSelectedsCells : [Int:String?] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return ButtonTableViewCell.cellHeigth
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ButtonTableViewCell
        {
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            var selectedText : String?
            if let currentSelectedText = self.dictOfSelectedsCells[indexPath.row]
            {
                selectedText = currentSelectedText
            }

            cell.setupWithClosure(texts:["Variant1","Variant2","Variant3","Variant4"], textSelected: selectedText, closure: { [weak self] (selected) in
                debugPrint(indexPath)
                self?.dictOfSelectedsCells[indexPath.row] = selected
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            })

            return cell
        }
        assert(false, "this must not happen")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов No you only have to define your customCell in your storyboard, i can post images to help you if you want

Comment: It is working I tried Thank  you. But can you edit your code to 4 buttons

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов check the repo https://github.com/rmelian2014/SOButtonsTableViewCellQuestion and test it, best regards

Comment: I think you didn't get what i mean, There should be 4 buttons in one cell

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов why you need 4 buttons in one cell when you can use 4 cells and one button on each one?, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: It is like quiz app and in one cell there is one question(textView) with 4 variants 4 variants are 4 buttons and when user clicked one it shows to user that he selected that variant. I tried your version it is working perfectly but i need to do this with 4 buttons in one cell. There is multiple questions it means that multiple cells thats why I need to implement 4 buttons to 1 cell

Comment: You can use Sections but I can modify my code @АзаматБулегенов

Comment: Please modify your code and upload it again with 4 buttons. Pleeeeeaseeeeeeeee!!!!

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов ok, i will try it but I need to sleep now, in 6hrs I will update my answer ok?

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов Check my answer and my repo was edited, let me know if solves your problem, happy coding

Comment: @АзаматБулегенов if solves your problem please accept the answer, if you need further help let me know, best regards

Answer (score 0):

In your **cellForRowAt indexPath:** method you need to check if the indexpath of the row is same as the indexpath of the selected button. if its same then you need to show the highlighted color otherwise the normal color.

so save the indexpath of the button pressed in a global variable in your buttonpressedmethod. let the valiable be selectedButtonIndexPath.

Add below code in your **cellForRowAt indexPath:** method

```
 if indexPath.row==selectedButtonIndexPath.row {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    } else {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 34/255, green: 89/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

And ofcourse reload  your tableview when a button is clicked to reflect the change in the color.

Update 1:

Can you try saving the tag of the button as well in your button pressed methods by getting sender.tag and then change your if condition

```
if indexPath.row==selectedButtonIndexPath.row  {
    if buttonTag == 1{
        variant1.backgroundcolor = UIColor.lightGray
        variant2.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 34/255, green: 89/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
        // and so on for all buttons.
    }else if buttonTag == 2{
        // same as above but for variant2
    }
} else {

}
```

Comment: I created global variable selectedButtonIndexPath and equated it to selected button indexpath and added the function that you wrote to cellForRowAt function it is not working.

Comment: Ok so trying to understand the scenario here now. Your each cell has 4 buttons variant1-4. And do you also have multiple cells in your tableview each having 4 buttons?

Because right now what your code deos is only change the color of variant 1 of the cell that is selected. Is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: just Variant 1  was just test for me in perfect the button that I pressed doesn't matter first or fourth button have to change color. I just wrote variant 1 to test and it is not working

Comment: Can you explain what is the scenario. globalIndexPath will give the cell which has been clicked and not the button in this case. So apart from saving that you will have to also save the button variant that was clicked and then your if condition should have both the checks of cell indexpath as well as variant type.

Comment: You can follow the below comment mentioned by Reinier or in your existing code, when you are saving globalIndexPath, save the tag of the button as well that is selected and then modify the if statement to check for which tag is clicked and change its color. so 2 checks will have to be in place. first for cell clicked using indexpath and then tag of the button that was clicked

Comment: @ Азамат Булегенов  Just added an update to the code. Can you try this way. It should work