# How to change the color of Button in one tableVIewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a multiple tableViewCells and each tableviewCell contains of 4 buttons. I need to change the color of the button when the button is pressed. I tried to use delegate method for UIButton. like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        } else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 34/255, green: 89/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

}

But it is change the color of button in all other cells. But I need to change the button color only in that cell that I have pressed. (I have 4 buttons in 1 cell and I want to change the color of that button that I pressed and only in that cell )
How I implemented My buttons and added the target functions to each button:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Questions.count
}
var variant1 = UIButton()
var variant2 = UIButton()
var variant3 = UIButton()
var variant4 = UIButton()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "finalCell")!
    variant1 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
    variant2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
    variant3 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    variant4 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton
        let questionTextView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView
        questionTextView.text = "\(Questions[indexPath.row].content!)"
        variant1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant1ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        variant2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant2ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        variant3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant3ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        variant4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant4ButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

}
```

There is the target functions of the buttons(I have identified the indexpath of button when it is pressed):

```
func variant1ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
}

func variant2ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
}

func variant3ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
}

func variant4ButtonPressed(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    let intIndexpath = Int((indexPath?.row)!)
}
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: Is this the same code as in -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135516/how-to-change-button-color-in-specific-tableviewcell/45136562?noredirect=1#comment77243174_45136562

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all you are not using delegate.

Second, you've defined your class `CustomButton` and you are setting your button as `UIButton`.

Replace this:

```
var variant1 = UIButton()
var variant2 = UIButton()
var variant3 = UIButton()
var variant4 = UIButton()
```

For this:

```
var variant1 = CustomButton()
var variant2 = CustomButton()
var variant3 = CustomButton()
var variant4 = CustomButton()
```

or simply override the function in your View Controller and delegate your button to self.

Comment: so it's not working. I suggest you to follow the two answers. Both say the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following change in your code

1.

```
var variant1 : CustomButton!
var variant2 : CustomButton!
var variant3 : CustomButton!
var variant4 : CustomButton!
```

2 Assign customclass  to button in cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "finalCell")!
    variant1 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! CustomButton
    variant2 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! CustomButton
    variant3 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(3) as! CustomButton
    variant4 = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! CustomButton
        let questionTextView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView
        questionTextView.text = "\(Questions[indexPath.row].content!)"
    variant1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant1ButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant2ButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant3ButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    variant4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.variant4ButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting 4 tags for all of your buttons. The number of tags needs to be equal to the total number of buttons that you have. So if you have two cells and 8 buttons, the tags should be 1...8. There are a lot of numbers so you need to create them in a loop and also look for the specific clicked button in a loop as well. I also suggest you to do that in a custom cell class.